# How much computing power is required to verify transactions on Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake

What is the theoretical computing power needed in order to verify transactions on the upcoming Proof-of-Stake switch. For instance, will this be something that we can do on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes light clients will be eventually able to run on Raspberry pi.

However until pruning arrives I think they will only be able to fetch block headers

https://ethcore.io/parity.html

Once pruning is here we will see full nodes on Raspberry pi and similar devices